# Simple section labeling with tidytext for plain text input

Tags: r, tidyverse, tidytext

I'm using `tidytext` (and the `tidyverse`) to analyze some text data (as in [Tidy Text Mining with R](http://tidytextmining.com/index.html)).

My input text file, `myfile.txt`, looks like this:

```
# Section 1 Name
Lorem ipsum dolor
sit amet ... (et cetera)
# Section 2 Name
<multiple lines here again>
```

with 60 or so sections.

I would like to generate a column `section_name` with the strings `"Category 1 Name"` or `"Category 2 Name"` as values for the corresponding lines. For instance, I have

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidytext)
library(stringr)

fname <- "myfile.txt"
all_text <- readLines(fname)
all_lines <- tibble(text = all_text)
tidiedtext <- all_lines %>%
  mutate(linenumber = row_number(),
         section_id = cumsum(str_detect(text, regex("^#", ignore_case = TRUE)))) %>%
  filter(!str_detect(text, regex("^#"))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

which adds a column in `tidiedtext` for the corresponding section number for each line.

Is it possible to add a single line to the call to `mutate()` to add such a column? Or is there another approach I ought to be using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an approach using `grepl` for simplicity with `if_else` and `tidyr::fill`, but there's nothing wrong with the original approach; it's pretty similar to one used in the tidytext book. Also note that filtering after adding line numbers will make some nonexistent. If it matters, add line numbers after `filter`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

text <- '# Section 1 Name
Lorem ipsum dolor
sit amet ... (et cetera)
# Section 2 Name
<multiple lines here again>'

all_lines <- data_frame(text = read_lines(text))

tidied <- all_lines %>% 
    mutate(line = row_number(),
           section = if_else(grepl('^#', text), text, NA_character_)) %>% 
  fill(section) %>% 
  filter(!grepl('^#', text))

tidied
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>                          text  line          section
#>                         <chr> <int>            <chr>
#> 1           Lorem ipsum dolor     2 # Section 1 Name
#> 2    sit amet ... (et cetera)     3 # Section 1 Name
#> 3 <multiple lines here again>     5 # Section 2 Name
```

Or if you just want to format the numbers you've already got, just add `section_name = paste('Category', section_id, 'Name')` to your `mutate` call.

Comment: Thanks! This is pretty much what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I don't wish to have you rewrite your entire script, but I just found the question interesting and thought to add a base R tentative:

```
parse_data <- function(file_name) {
  all_rows <- readLines(file_name)
  indices <- which(grepl('#', all_rows))
  splitter <- rep(indices, diff(c(indices, length(all_rows)+1)))
  lst <- split(all_rows, splitter)
  lst <- lapply(lst, function(x) {
    data.frame(section=x[1], value=x[-1], stringsAsFactors = F)
  })
  line_nums = seq_along(all_rows)[-indices]
  df <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, lst)
  cbind.data.frame(df, linenumber = line_nums)
}
```

Testing with a file named `ipsum_data.txt`:

```
parse_data('ipsum_data.txt')
```

yields:

```
 text                        section          linenumber
 Lorem ipsum dolor           # Section 1 Name 2         
 sit amet ... (et cetera)    # Section 1 Name 3         
 <multiple lines here again> # Section 2 Name 5
```

The file `ipsum_data.txt` contains:

```
# Section 1 Name
Lorem ipsum dolor
sit amet ... (et cetera)
# Section 2 Name
<multiple lines here again>
```

I hope this proves useful.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is very helpful.

It's not a big deal for me to rewrite the script, but I think the other solution is more what I was looking for in terms of conciseness.